# Passing structure to a method in Java

Tags: java, php, arrays

I have this function so far:

```
public void passSomething (String[] texts);
```

this accepts strings only, but what if I have to pass more string, numbers (structure)? Like in php for example

```
$obj->passSomething (array(
    array('val1', 2),
    array('val2', 1),
    array('val3', 4)
);
```

how to do this in Java? Only with `class`?

Comment: `passSomething(String[]{'val1','val2','val3'})`

Comment: but what if I must pass int, Datetime, float etc?

Comment: pass super class `Object`, it can hold all type of object reference

Comment: it doesnt work somehow, Syntax errors on token

Comment: can you please show ur code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need to take a look at `Java` [Generic](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/types.html)

```
public <T> void printArray(T[] arr) {

}
```